# How to filter where a condition is true at least once

Tags: sql

I need to filter down to only service orders that have a "service" work group value in at least one of their tasks. However, I don't want to get rid of the rows that aren't work group = "Service" if at least one of the task rows has that value. The end result would leave out all data from service orders that didn't have at least one BI_WRKFLW_TASK_KEY that was equal to "SERVICE". I know how to do normal filters but getting it to this specificity is beyond my current experience.

I've experimented with normal filters but they leave out rows that are a part of the same Service Order but just don't have that work group.

```
SELECT W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY, 
       T.BI_WORK_EVENT_CD, 
       T.BI_TASK_CD, 
       T.BI_WORKGRP, 
       **M.BI_SO_NBR**, 
       M.BI_SO_TYPE_CD, 
       M.BI_CLOSE_DT,
       M.BI_OPEN_DT, 
       M.BI_SO_STAT_CD, 
       R.BI_WRKFLW_TMPLT_NM, 
       T.BI_WRKFLW_TASK_SEQ_NBR, 
       T.BI_WORKGRP, 
       A.BI_WORK_EVENT_CD,
       A.BI_EVENT_DT_TM, 
       A.SY_JOB_QUEUE_ID, 
       **A.BI_WORKGRP**, 
       A.SY_USER_ID, 
       **A.BI_WRKFLW_TASK_KEY**
FROM BI_WRKFLW W
         LEFT JOIN BI_WRKFLW_TASKS T ON W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = T.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
         LEFT JOIN BI_SO_DET D ON W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = D.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
         LEFT JOIN BI_SO_MASTER M ON D.BI_SO_NBR = M.BI_SO_NBR
         LEFT JOIN BI_WRKFLW_TMPLT_REF R ON W.BI_WRKFLW_TMPLT_ID = R.BI_WRKFLW_TMPLT_ID
         LEFT JOIN BI_TASK_ACT A ON T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = A.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY
WHERE M.BI_OPEN_DT >= ADD_MONTHS(CURRENT_DATE, -'12')
--AND M.BI_SO_TYPE_CD IN ('IVC-NEW1') 
--AND M.BI_SO_STAT_CD LIKE 'O'  
ORDER BY M.BI_SO_NBR, T.BI_EVENT_DT_TM
```

Any Service order row where the Service order has at least one BI_WRKFLOW_TASK_CD = "Service" would be kept and all other service orders filtered out.

Comment: I've put **s surrounding key fields for this problem.

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: So you might just want `OR`. Put that whole chain in parentheses.

Comment: This is a classic case for `WHERE EXISTS(select ...)`. Without the schema it's a bit hard to write up an example for you. If you provide minimal examples of your tables and data, it would be pretty easy to whip up a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to map this out, i may not have got it quite right,

I think you are asking for BI_SO_MASTER records that have >=1  BI_WRKFLW_TASKS that belong to a certain group.

Try using a CTE to get the detail rows with a correct task, then you can find the SO population... then you can ???not sure what the ultimate result set goal is?

```
;with matchingTasks as (    D.BI_SO_NBR, D.<id> , W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY , T.<key> , A.Key
from BI_WRKFLW W
LEFT JOIN BI_WRKFLW_TASKS T ON W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = T.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
LEFT JOIN BI_SO_DET D ON W.BI_WRKFLW_KEY = D.BI_WRKFLW_KEY
LEFT JOIN BI_TASK_ACT A ON T.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEY = A.BI_WRKFLW_TASKS_KEYW
Where 
    <good dates> 
    and <A.field is what I am looking for>
)
/*Here you have the SO population
as well as the ids that helped this SO qualify. 
*/
, My_SO_Population as (select Distinct BI_SO_NBR from matchingTasks   )

/*now you can go get what you need. 
the challenge of finding SOs w/ >=1 matching task has been solved...
*/
   select  <necessary fields> from    
My_SO_Population 
join   <whatever you need....this is where i am cloudy>
```

if i am missing the goal, let me know where...

Answer (score 0):

You can just add this to your `WHERE` clause:

```
AND T.BI_WRKFLW_KEY IN (
    SELECT BI_WRKFLW_KEY
    FROM BI_WRKFLW_TASKS
    WHERE BI_WRKFLOW_TASK_CD = 'Service')
```